# выделение выбранного пункта меню

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, как выделять пункт меню сайта на странице которого я нахожусь.
т.е. у меня есть меню

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Roboto", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.navbar-menu_item{
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-menu">
  <a class="navbar-menu_item" href="/ru/">О нас</a>
  <a class="navbar-menu_item" href="/ru/news">Новости</a>
  <a class="navbar-menu_item" href="/ru/job">Карьера</a>
  <a class="navbar-menu_item" href="/ru/contacts">Контакты</a>
</div>
```

при переходе по ссылкам , открываются новые страницы.
пытаюсь добавить класс к текущей странице так

```js
const navbar = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar-menu_item");
for (let index = 0; index < navbar.length; index++) {
  const navbarLink = navbar[index];
  navbarLink.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log(navbarLink)
    navbarLink.classList.add('test')
  })
}
```

класс добавляется, это видно если после добавления добавить  `e.preventDefault();`
но при переходе на страницу класса нет. Подскажите как такое реализовать

Comment: После переходе на новую страницу, состояние установленное на предыдущей теряется(если конечно у вас не SPA), почему вы не рассматриваете вариант присвоения класса активному пункту меню после перехода, путем сравнения текущего `location.pathname` c `href` ваших ссылок меню?

Comment: @MikalaiParakhnevich не SPA , я не знал про такой вариант. Не расскажите подробней?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так должно работать

```
let a = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-menu_item')
a.forEach((el)=>{
  if (el.getAttribute('href') == window.location.pathname) el.classList.add('test')  
})
```